Cant create an image using matplotlib and python in VsCode (UserWarning: FigureCanvasAgg is non-interactive, and thus cannot be shown plt.show())
I am trying to create a graph using matplotlib and I keep getting an error saying: "UserWarning: FigureCanvasAgg is non-interactive, and thus cannot be shown plt.show()". I've tried installing tkinter as I read that could help but when I try running it, it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'. I've also tried install PyQt6 but that didn't seem to help either. Does anyone have any possible fixes so I can get an image to display in VsCode or at least to export the image?
I've tried installing tkinter using (pip install tk) as I read that could help but when I try running it, it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'. I've also tried install PyQt6 but that didn't seem to help either.

Show code with a [mcve] and desired outcome. Tkinter comes with Python unless you deselected it during installation

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

PyQt6 did not work for me either. I put the following files in my requirements.txt
PyQt5==5.15.11
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.14
PyQt5_sip==12.15.0

pip install -r requirements.txt
That's all. It works for me.
You may need to ensure that interactive backend is using Qt by putting the following code in the beginning of your file
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('qtagg') 


You can also try adding plt.isinteractive()
